# AppleScript — get application by its name string

Tags: macos, applescript

This code works well.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set bounds of window "File" of application "TextEdit" to {0, 0, 0, 0}
end tell
```

And this code does not work. How can this be fixed?

```
tell application "System Events"
    set appName to "TextEdit"
    set bounds of window "File" of application appName to {0, 0, 0, 0}
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about two different things.

1. Access elements and properties of a **scriptable application.**
   In this case `System Events` is not needed but the name of the target *application*  is required to be a literal string (evaluation of the terminology at compile time).

   ```
   set bounds of window "File" of application "TextEdit" to {0, 0, 0, 0}
   ```
2. Access elements and properties of **UI elements of an application process** (scriptable or not). 
   In this case you have to use `System Events` and specify an *application process*. The name of the target process can be passed in a variable.

   ```
   tell application "System Events"
       set appName to "TextEdit"
       tell process appName
          set bounds of window "File" to {0, 0, 0, 0}
       end tell
   end tell
   ```

In both cases it's not guaranteed that the target application or the target process have a `window` element containing the `bounds` property.